# NameError, python3 get_step not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I'm following the book "Python crash Course" and i keep getting this

> NameError: name 'get_step' is not defined

It's in python3 and both files are in the same directory.

So..the function is defined inside this class:

[image: random_walk.py]

and the class is imported to:

[image: main_program]

where it calls fill_walks, and fill_walks calls get_step. What am i missing here? can someone help me please

Comment: When including code with your questions, please include the text of the code rather than screenshots. Read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know how when you refer to `x_values`, `y_values`, and `num_points`, you have to say `self.x_values`, `self.y_values`, etc? This is true for all attributes of your instance, including methods. So when you want to do `get_step()` and `get_step` is defined on your class, you have to call `self.get_step()`.

In addition, when you define a method on your class, by default it's what's called an instance method, and will automatically be called with the instance as the first argument. You've defined `fill_walk` correctly, with `def fill_walk(self):` but `get_step` is currently not defined properly. You either have to do

```
def get_step(self):
    ....
```

or, since get_step doesn't itself need to access any instance attributes, you can mark it as a static method by defining it like so:

```
@staticmethod
def get_step():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

in random_walk.py
change

```
def get_step():
```

to

```
def get_step(self):     #<--- self?
```

Comment: This by itself won't help - they also need to replace the calls to `get_step()` with `self.get_step()`.

Comment: True, but we don't know where he is calling get_step()

Comment: It's right there in the screenshot - lines 21 and 22.